# Confusion on "for /l in %%i ..." always renders "0"

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, primes

I'm a little confused on why in this code, %rem% always comes back as 0 (even when tested with prime numbers). Can someone please help me? Thanks :D

```
:PRIME
cls
echo What number would you like to check?
set /p num=
set num2=%num%-1
for /l %%i in (2 1 %num2%) do (
    set /a rem=%num% %% %%i
)
if %rem% equ 0 goto NOT_PRIME
goto YES_PRIME

:YES_PRIME
echo %num% is a prime number.
goto AGAIN_PRIME

:NOT_PRIME
echo %num% is not a prime number.
goto AGAIN_PRIME

:AGAIN_PRIME
echo Would you like to check another number? (y/n)
set /p ans=
if '%ans%'=='y' goto PRIME
if '%ans%'=='n' goto START
```

This is only a portion of the code. The problem is that every number that I test, I get "%num% is not a prime number."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in this section:

```
set num2=%num%-1
for /l %%i in (2 1 %num2%) do (
    set /a rem=%num% %% %%i
)
if %rem% equ 0 goto NOT_PRIME
```

First, you need to use `set /a` to do calculations on a variable, so it should be:

```
set /a num2=%num%-1
```

Second, your `for` loop runs through all your calculations correctly, but your `if` line ends up checking only the results of the very last calculation.  You need to enable delayed expansion and then include the `if` statement inside the `for` loop, like this:

```
for /l %%i in (2 1 %num2%) do (
    set /a rem=%num% %% %%i
    if !rem! equ 0 goto NOT_PRIME
)
```

Comment: You can simply use `num` with SET /A. You don't need `%num%`.